# Result of request SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following request that must return result :

```
select ass.* 
from CTR_ASSURANCE ass 
inner join CTR_ARTICLEASSURANCE ca on ass.CODE_CONTRAT = ca.CODE_CONTRAT
WHERE  
   (GETDATE() between ass.DATE_DEBUT and ass.DATE_FIN)
   and ass.resilie <> 1 
   and ca.CODE_ARTICLE = 39
```

in database there is a row that satisfies this condition but the request doesn't return any result, the problem is in `ass.resilie <> 1`. This column is numeric and all rows have 'resilie' null
help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IS` operator to compare with `NULL`. Replace

```
ass.resilie<>1
```

with

```
(ass.resilie IS NULL OR ass.resilie <> 1)
```